# Couchbase : querying with Nickel using indexes, but the indexes do not get updated immediatel

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am facing a problem here I am querying Couchbase using Nickel and my query is

```
SELECT  *        
FROM `user`
USE INDEX (ord_ts_new_idx USING GSI)
WHERE META(`user`).id LIKE 'ord::27::%'
ORDER BY ts DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 5;
```

But here the value that I am getting is not updated, But If I make the same request after sometime It gives me the desired output.

The query that I have used for making the INDEX is

```
CREATE INDEX ord_ts_new_idx ON `user-account`(`ts`) USING GSI;
```

where `ts` is the `TimeStamp`.

So could you please tell me if there is a way in which, I can get the updated data always?

Thanks in advance. Any type of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not mention which SDK you are using, but client SDK are you using? N1QL provides a scan_consistency parameter, so it's a matter of making sure your client SDK uses this. So go [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/intro.html) and find your language of choice. For example, [here is the Java SDK section](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/java-2.2/querying-n1ql.html), look under "read your own write."

Just be forewarned that by doing this for everything, you could very well take a performance penalty as the index will need to be refreshed before serving your results. So make sure you test this please.

Comment: Yeah I have already tried this but everytime I fire this query it gives me a timeout exception. I have tested it by increasing the timeout to 500 sec but still its not working